# pseudoelement works in Firefox but not Chrome, why?

Tags: css

I am trying to use a pseudoelement to replace the `<li>` for `<ul>` with a triangle.  I followed [this tutorial.](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/color-bullets.en.html)

The problem is that my CSS works in Firefox but not Chrome on Windows.

Here is my CSS:

```
article ul {
  list-style: none;
}
article ul > li::before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0da";
  color: $darkbrown;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  margin-left: -1em
}
```

I am targeting **article** because I have `<ul>` in the header and footer that I do not want to apply the triangle to.

In Firefox, this works as expected (`<ul>` in the article have the triangle, and `<ol>` in the article show numbers).  However, in Chrome, the `<ul>` in the article have a triangle, but the `<ol>` in the article also have triangles.

Here's an example of the HTML (sorry, it's from Drupal and a little ugly; I cleaned it up as best I could):

```
<body class="path-node page-node-type-lp navbar-is-static-top has-glyphicons">
<a href="#main-content" class="visually-hidden focusable skip-link">
    メインコンテンツに移動
</a>
<div role="main" class="main-container container js-quickedit-main-content">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-12" role="heading">

            <section class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12">


                        <a id="main-content"></a>
                        <div class="region region-content">
                            <article role="article" about="/myurl" class="lp full clearfix">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="layout layout--onecol">
                                        <div class="layout__region layout__region--content">
                                            <section
                                                    class="block block-layout-builder block-field-blocknodelpbody clearfix">
                                                <div class="field field--name-body field--type-text-with-summary field--label-hidden field--item">
                                                    <ol>
                                                        <li>item 1</li>
                                                        <li>item 2</li>
                                                        <li>item 3</li>
                                                    </ol>
                                                </div>
                                            </section>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Got some HTML for this so we can see the issue for ourselves?

Comment: What he said. I whipped together a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/pj8rze3L/), but it works as expected in both browsers, so there is something wrong in a part of your code that you're not showing.

Comment: @BoltClock I've added an example of the failing HTML.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks, I added an example of the failing HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem, which related to inlining critical css using the Drupal CriticalCSS module.

Basically, what happened is that I had generated the critical CSS based on old CSS, and this inline css (the critical CSS) was overriding the working CSS in the file I was editing.

Apparently, Firefox gives priority to the non-inline CSS, while Chrome and Edge prioritize the inline CSS, hence the reason for the difference in what was displayed.

Lesson learned: **Make sure any inline CSS is current when editing CSS.** (I am looking in to ways to automate that right now.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i'm understanding your issue as your code appears to work the way you intend. I've added a `<ul>` inside your `<article>` to show that it has a triangle next to it while the `<ol>` shows the default numbering. Try browsing this example in Chrome to see the results.

```css
article ul {
  list-style: none;
}

article ul>li::before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0da";
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  margin-left: -1em
}
```

```html
<a href="#main-content" class="visually-hidden focusable skip-link">
    メインコンテンツに移動
</a>
<div role="main" class="main-container container js-quickedit-main-content">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-12" role="heading">

      <section class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-1"></div>
          <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12">


            <a id="main-content"></a>
            <div class="region region-content">
              <article role="article" about="/myurl" class="lp full clearfix">
                <div class="content">
                  <div class="layout layout--onecol">
                    <div class="layout__region layout__region--content">
                      <section class="block block-layout-builder block-field-blocknodelpbody clearfix">
                        <div class="field field--name-body field--type-text-with-summary field--label-hidden field--item">
                          <ol>
                            <li>item 1</li>
                            <li>item 2</li>
                            <li>item 3</li>
                          </ol>
                          <ul>
                            <li>item 1</li>
                            <li>item 2</li>
                            <li>item 3</li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </section>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </article>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would be better off as a comment than an answer. Also, your ul does not show triangles.